# Column Type Conversion in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I Want to convert entire column to the type(number)

[image]

Example In the above image the some data are of type string and some are of type number I want all the data in the entire column as a type number.

Comment: When you select all the cells, there should be a little popup that alerts you that the numbers are stored as text (since the first cell is) and has an option to convert to numbers.

Comment: You can use function or copy and then paste special.

Comment: But if these are contract numbers (identifiers) then it may be better to store them as text, e.g. you may need the leading zeros in comparisons with data from other sources, and you are not going to add, subtract, multiply, divide and raise to power these numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the cells format to General before re-entering the values.

```
 Sub tt()
  col = "A"
  lastRowIndex = Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
  Set c = Range(Cells(1, col), Cells(lastRowIndex, col))
  c.NumberFormat = ""
  c.FormulaLocal = c.Value
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Sub ShivaGupta ()

        Columns("nameofcolumn").NumberFormat = "0.00"

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an Excel formula, you may try this one:

```
=VALUE(A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

tombata's answer seems a good way to go, however, you might also go through each with a *for* loop and convert each cell's `.value` using CInt() or CDouble() depending on your needs.

[Type Conversion Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx)